# Quadratic Equations in two-variables.

Tags: quadratics

Determine the number of ordered pairs $(x, y)$ of positive integers satisfying the
equation $x^2+y^2-16y=2004$.

My solution:

$x^2+y^2-16y=2004$

$\Rightarrow x^2=2004-y^2+16y$

$\Rightarrow x=\sqrt{2004-y^2+16y}$

Now, plugging in integers on the R.H.S. for $y=1$ to $53$ (since both $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, and for $y>53$, $x$ is imaginary), (on Excel);

I do not get any pair of $x$ & $y$; where both are positive integers.

Answer : $0$

Is this solution correct?, and is there a smarter way to solve this problem?

Comment: Thank you @Parcly Taxel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zero is correct, but a much faster way follows. Complete the square first:
$$x^2+y^2-16y+64=2004+64$$
$$x^2+(y-8)^2=2068=4×11×47$$
$11\equiv3\bmod4$ and it appears only once in the prime factorisation, so no pair $(x,y)$ satisfies the given equation by the [sum of two squares theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem).

Comment: Thank You very much for the solution...Greatly appreciated.